# how to get div content with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, simple-html-dom

i want get content div class(.p-available-stock)
but it's give me just empty Brackets => () => And do not bring me what's inside

```
include("phpdom/simple_html_dom.php");

    $html=file_get_html("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2017-Kids-Baby-Sweater-clothes-sets-2PCS-Winter-Newborn-baby-cotton-Long-sleeve-Top-pants-Fashion/32794929322.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.369.58a4e0a3HHUVH3&s=p&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_10313_10059_10340_10341_10534_100031_10084_10604_10617_10083_10616_10103_10307_10615_10142,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_4&algo_expid=82c85051-8e8e-42bd-8a6e-0f39e5b0ba1a-47&algo_pvid=82c85051-8e8e-42bd-8a6e-0f39e5b0ba1a&transAbTest=ae803_4&priceBeautifyAB=1");

    $title=$html->find(".p-available-stock");
    foreach ($title as $key) {
        echo $key;
    }
```

Comment: Its not on the dom the actual value is brought in with ajax and put into. `<em data-role="stock-num" id="j-sell-stock-num"></em>`

Comment: how i will do that with ajax ?

Comment: Just load the ajax url and parse it.